# Excel error "object doesn't support this property or method" on "HomeKey Unit:=wdStory"

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm trying to open all .docx files in a specified folder (and all subfolders) and replace the text contained within "strFindText1" variable with the text in "strReplaceText1".

I found an example of the code online and adapted it.

It gives the error

> "Object doesn't support this property or method"

at `.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory`.

```
Sub FindAndReplaceInFolder()
  Dim objDoc As Document
  Dim strFile As String
  Dim strFolder As String
  Dim strFindText As String
  Dim strReplaceText As String
 
  '  Pop up input boxes for user to enter folder path
  strFolder = InputBox("Enter folder path here:")
  strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\" & "*.docx", vbNormal)
  strFindText1 = "text_sample"
  strReplaceText1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Value
 
  '  Open each file in the folder to search and replace texts. Save and close the file after the action.
  While strFile <> ""
    Set objDoc = Documents.Open(Filename:=strFolder & "\" & strFile)
    With objDoc
      With Selection
        .HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
        With Selection.Find
          .Text = strFindText1
          .Replacement.Text = strReplaceText1
          .Forward = True
          .Wrap = wdFindContinue
          .Format = False
          .MatchCase = False
          .MatchWholeWord = False
          .MatchWildcards = False
          .MatchSoundsLike = False
          .MatchAllWordForms = False
        End With
        Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
      End With
      objDoc.Save
      objDoc.Close
      strFile = Dir()
    End With
  Wend
End Sub
```

I will be running the macro from an Excel file to modify all Word files.

Comment: If this is being run from Excel then the error is because VBA will assume `Selection` refers to a selection in Excel. `Selection` will need to be qualified with the object variable used for the `Word.Application` object. Since you don't show us that part of the code it's not possible to be more precise. But I can tell you that there are a lot of code examples around with using `Find` in Word from Excel VBA. You might want to locate a few of those...

Comment: With objDoc
      With Selection
        .HomeKey Unit:=wdStory is ambiguous, at best. The newly opened objDoc has no selection and Excel's ActiveSheet, which does have a selection, isn't known. It's always good advice not to use the Selection object at all. Assign its value to a string and use that string.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues with your code. For example, you specify:

```
Dim objDoc As Document
```

but there is no indication whether you're using early or late binding; you don't even have a line referencing the Word application. If you were using early binding, I'd expect to see something like:

```
Dim wdApp As New Word.Application, wdDoc as Word.Document
```

For late binding, I'd expect to see something like:

```
Dim objWord as Object, objDoc As Object
```

plus code to instantiate Word. You'd then use either:

```
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(Filename:=strFolder & "\" & strFile)
```

or:

```
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(Filename:=strFolder & "\" & strFile)
```

as appropriate.

Moreover, your document processing code could be improved. For example, you might replace all of:

```
With objDoc
  With Selection
    .HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    With Selection.Find
      .Text = strFindText1
      .Replacement.Text = strReplaceText1
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindContinue
      .Format = False
      .MatchCase = False
      .MatchWholeWord = False
      .MatchWildcards = False
      .MatchSoundsLike = False
      .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
  objDoc.Save
  objDoc.Close
```

with:

```
With objDoc
  With .Range.Find
    .Text = strFindText1
    .Replacement.Text = strReplaceText1
    .Forward = True
    .Format = False
    .Wrap = 1 'wdFindContinue
    .Execute Replace:=2 'wdReplaceAll
  End With
  .Close True
End With
```

For some code to get you started, try:

```
 Sub BulkFindReplace()
'Note: this code requires a reference to the Word object model.
'See under the VBE's Tools|References.
Dim wdApp As New Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document
Dim strFolder As String, strFile As String, StrFnd As String, StrRep As String
strFolder = GetFolder
If strFolder = "" Then Exit Sub
StrFnd = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Value
StrRep = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D2").Value
strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\*.docx", vbNormal)
While strFile <> ""
  Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(Filename:=strFolder & "\" & strFile, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
  With wdDoc
    With .Range.Find
      .Text = StrFnd
      .Replacement.Text = StrRep
      .Forward = True
      .Format = False
      .Wrap = wdFindContinue
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
    .Close SaveChanges:=True
  End With
  strFile = Dir()
Wend
wdApp.Quit
Set wdDoc = Nothing: Set wdApp = Nothing
End Sub
 
Function GetFolder() As String
    Dim oFolder As Object
    GetFolder = ""
    Set oFolder = CreateObject("Shell.Application").BrowseForFolder(0, "Choose a folder", 0)
    If (Not oFolder Is Nothing) Then GetFolder = oFolder.Items.Item.Path
    Set oFolder = Nothing
End Function
```